# Draw a semi circle using bash and loops only

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to draw a semi circle in bash using for loops only. The scrpit shall generate the semi circle out of the users input and print it afterwards. My problem is to get the whitespace between prints. Can anybody help me. This is what I got so far - I know that this one produces an upside down pyramid but the idea was to only get the diagonals and put in more "O" in the last line so that it produces a kind of a semi circle.

```
read -p "Semi Circle length: " n

for(( i=$n ; i>=1 ; i-- ))
do
        for(( j=($n-i) ; j>=1 ; j-- ))
        do
            echo -n " "
        done

        for(( k=(2*$i)-1 ; k>=1 ; k-- ))
        do
            echo -n "O"
        done
        echo
done
```

This outputs

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
 OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
  OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
   OOOOOOOOOOOOO
    OOOOOOOOOOO
     OOOOOOOOO
      OOOOOOO
       OOOOO
        OOO
         O
```

I want something more like

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
 OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
 OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
  OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
   OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOO
      OOOOOOOOOO
          OO
```

[image: The output should be something like this]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the actual and expected output.

Comment: Maybe you can derive something from this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#bash (But it is not a trivial task.)

Comment: Try `echo ◠` :-)

Comment: @meliodas, I added some outputs. Is that what you mean?

Comment: it is a geometric problem: in this case, you need to use trigonometric function **sine** and **cosine**

Comment: Pythagorean theorem is sufficient.

Comment: I only want to get the border of a semi circle without really filling up the circle

Comment: Doing stuff with trigonometry or square roots is really not something you want to do in a shell. This is one of those cases where you really want a real programming language.

Comment: What do you mean by "_My problem is to get the whitespace between prints_"? (Please [edit] your question to explain this; ideally with an example.)

Comment: @ikkachu Some of us remember the days or writing versions of space invaders on an 8k Commodore PET and animating the invaders walking `()` and `)(` by shifting one cell at a time. Oh, such simple days. And when Atari introduced sprites,,,,,,,heaven! No more updating screen action on a vblank interrupt in Z80A machine code with microseconds to spare to avoid flicker...... I feel young again today ;-D

Comment: @roaima it was meant like in the answer below. I only could get a circle which also had the * inside of it but i only wantet to get the border of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @saga trig a little more

```
read -p "Semi Circle radius tolerance: " n w
R2=$((n*n))

for(( x=-$n ; x<=$n ; x+=2 )); do
    for ((y=-$n ; y<=$n ; y++)); do
        d=$((x*x + y*y))
        if [ $((d-R2)) -lt $w ] && [ $((R2-d)) -lt $w ] ; then echo -n "*"; else echo -n " "; fi
    done
    echo 
done
```

Output for radius 20 & tolerance 10

```
                *******                 
           *                 *           
        *                       *        
      *                           *      
    *                               *    


 *                                     * 

*                                       *
*                                       *
*                                       *

 *                                     * 


    *                               *    
      *                           *      
        *                       *        
           *                 *           
                 *******
```

For the full semicircle experience

```
read -p "Semi Circle radius tolerance: " n w
R2=$((n*n))

echo
for(( x=0 ; x>=-$n ; x-=2 )); do
    for ((y=-$n ; y<=$n ; y++)); do
        d=$((x*x + y*y))
        if [ $((d-R2)) -lt $w ] && [ $((R2-d)) -lt $w ] || [ $x -eq 0 ]; then echo -n "*"; else echo -n " "; fi
    done
    echo 
done
echo
```

With radius 20 and tolerance 12

```
*****************************************
*                                       *

 *                                     * 

   *                                 *   
    *                               *    
      *                           *      
        *                       *        
           *                 *           
                 *******
```

**edit**

Purely for fun, added a box to avoid clipping, sensibly renamed variables  and refined the test for tolerance to the radius to a single condition.

```
read -p "Circle enter: radius tolerance.... " r t
r2=$((r*r))
t2=$((t*t))
box=$((r+t/10))
for(( y=-$box ; y<=$box ; y+=2 )); do
    for ((x=-$box ; x<=$box ; x++)); do
        d=$((x*x + y*y-r2))
        d2=$((d*d))
        if [ $d2 -lt $t2 ]; then echo -n "*"; else echo -n " "; fi
    done
    echo 
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that was really helpful. its even much more than i needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
read -p "Semi Circle radius: " n
R2=$((n*n))


for(( i=1 ; i<=5+$n ; i++ ))
do
        for(( j=2*$n ; j>=1 ; j-- ))
        do
            D=$((i*i + (j-n)*(j-n)))
            if [ $D -lt $R2 ]; then echo -n '#' ;>
        done
        echo
done
```